# How to patch a class from the same module as the class under test

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have two classes defined in the same module. A method in the second class is calling a method in the first class.  I want to construct a test for the method in the second to confirm that it correctly calls the the first class, however I have some problems getting the syntax correct to patch the class.

Here is a sample of the code I have:

content_provider.py:

```
class ContentUser():
    def getUserRef(self, username):
        ...
        return userRef

class ContentReportGeneralSearch():
    def getReport(self,username,search_text,search_type='0'):
        user = ContentUser()
        user.getUserRef(username=username)
        ....
```

test_content_provider.py:

```
@mock.patch('content_provider.ContentUser')
def test_getReport(self):
    provider = ContentReportGeneralSearch()
    provider.getReport(username='test',search_text='')
    mock_user.getUserRef.assert_called_once_with(username='test')
```

When I run this test I get the result:

> AssertionError: Expected 'getUserRef' to be called once. Called 0 times.

I suspect the problem is with the way I specify the patch, however I have tried various ways to do it without any success.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, here is the unit test solution:

`content_provider.py`:

```py
class ContentUser():
    def getUserRef(self, username):
        userRef = ''
        return userRef


class ContentReportGeneralSearch():
    def getReport(self, username, search_text, search_type='0'):
        user = ContentUser()
        user.getUserRef(username=username)
```

`test_content_provider.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from content_provider import ContentReportGeneralSearch


class TestContentProvider(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('content_provider.ContentUser')
    def test_getReport(self, mock_ContentUser):
        content_user_instance = mock_ContentUser.return_value
        provider = ContentReportGeneralSearch()
        provider.getReport(username='test', search_text='')
        content_user_instance.getUserRef.assert_called_once_with(username='test')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                                  Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/54841363/content_provider.py            8      2    75%   3-4
src/stackoverflow/54841363/test_content_provider.py      11      0   100%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                                    19      2    89%
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/54841363